Bootstrap Collapse on unordered list doesn't react on first click
I have created a filetree page on a website and added some bootstrap collapse stuff which basically does all I want. The list of files and folders is shown with all tree branches uncollapsed initially. But when I click on a folder symbol (button) in order to collapse the relevant folder content, it doesn't work but for the second click.
I guess I have to initialize some JavaScript stuff but have no idea where to look for the right spot in my included .js files.
Any help is appreciated.


<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://www.cirp.org/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://www.cirp.org/css/cirp.css'>


<script src='https://www.cirp.org/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'></script>


<h1>CIRP.org FileTree</h1>
<ul class='collapse.show' id='UL0'>
    <li><img src='https://www.cirp.org/fonts/bi/folder.svg' alt='Folder' title='Folder' width='20' height='20' role='button' data-bs-toggle='collapse' data-bs-target='#UL1' aria-controls='UL1' aria-expanded='true'>&nbsp;<b><a href='/AAP'>AAP</a></b></li>
    <ul class='collapse.show' id='UL1'>
        <li><img src='https://www.cirp.org/fonts/bi/folder.svg' alt='Folder' title='Folder' width='20' height='20' role='button' data-bs-toggle='collapse' data-bs-target='#UL2' aria-controls='UL2' aria-expanded='true'>&nbsp;<b><a href='/AAP/articles'>articles</a></b></li>
        <ul class='collapse.show' id='UL2'>
            <li><img src='https://www.cirp.org/fonts/bi/folder.svg' alt='Folder' title='Folder' width='20' height='20' role='button' data-bs-toggle='collapse' data-bs-target='#UL3' aria-controls='UL3' aria-expanded='true'>&nbsp;<b><a href='/AAP/articles/tobacco'>tobacco</a></b></li>
            <ul class='collapse.show' id='UL3'>
                <li><a href='/AAP/articles/tobacco/index.php'>The role of tobacco in penile carcinoma</a></li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
        <li><a href='/AAP/docs.php'>Circumcision Documentation for AAP Task Force</a></li>
        <li><a href='/AAP/history.php'>History of AAP's Position on Circumcision</a></li>
        <li><a href='/AAP/index.php'>American Academy of Pediatrics Circumcision Task Force Monitor page</a></li>
        <li><a href='/AAP/taskforce.php'>The 1999 AAP Task Force on Neonatal Circumcision</a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>




Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?

You should match the state of the <ul> with the correct classes. You can see those toggled in and out as you expand and collapse some branch.
So all it takes is to add classes collapse show to the expanded lists.


<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://www.cirp.org/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://www.cirp.org/css/cirp.css'>


<script src='https://www.cirp.org/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'></script>


<h1>CIRP.org FileTree</h1>
<ul class='collapse.show collapse show' id='UL0'>
    <li><img src='https://www.cirp.org/fonts/bi/folder.svg' alt='Folder' title='Folder' width='20' height='20' role='button' data-bs-toggle='collapse' data-bs-target='#UL1' aria-controls='UL1' aria-expanded='true'>&nbsp;<b><a href='/AAP'>AAP</a></b></li>
    <ul class='collapse.show collapse show' id='UL1'>
        <li><img src='https://www.cirp.org/fonts/bi/folder.svg' alt='Folder' title='Folder' width='20' height='20' role='button' data-bs-toggle='collapse' data-bs-target='#UL2' aria-controls='UL2' aria-expanded='true'>&nbsp;<b><a href='/AAP/articles'>articles</a></b></li>
        <ul class='collapse.show collapse show' id='UL2'>
            <li><img src='https://www.cirp.org/fonts/bi/folder.svg' alt='Folder' title='Folder' width='20' height='20' role='button' data-bs-toggle='collapse' data-bs-target='#UL3' aria-controls='UL3' aria-expanded='true'>&nbsp;<b><a href='/AAP/articles/tobacco'>tobacco</a></b></li>
            <ul class='collapse.show collapse show' id='UL3'>
                <li><a href='/AAP/articles/tobacco/index.php'>The role of tobacco in penile carcinoma</a></li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
        <li><a href='/AAP/docs.php'>Circumcision Documentation for AAP Task Force</a></li>
        <li><a href='/AAP/history.php'>History of AAP's Position on Circumcision</a></li>
        <li><a href='/AAP/index.php'>American Academy of Pediatrics Circumcision Task Force Monitor page</a></li>
        <li><a href='/AAP/taskforce.php'>The 1999 AAP Task Force on Neonatal Circumcision</a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>




Excellent, thank you for your quick reply and perfect help.

Could you please avoid answering questions that obviously should be closed? Thank you.

@UlfDunkel I really don't see what is weird about it. Good questions (and answers) get upvoted. Bad ones get downvoted. Eventually they get closed, and possibly deleted. You have received an edit comment + a comment telling you what was wrong with your question. There is also a section in the help which explains why Not all questions can or should be answered here, hence my above comment, which btw isn't aggressive. I wouldn't have said Could you please avoid if my intent was to be aggressive.

And kindly note that voting isn't definitive. Edit your question so that it fits the canvas and people might remove their (down)votes. Even close votes can be retracted and already closed question reopened.
